# Change length.out in ifelse function

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm running a simple ifelse function

```
f <- function(x) {
ifelse(x==shift(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
}
```

where shift is from the data.table package

which allows me to change, for each column in a dataframe (usig **apply**), a value which is exactly the same as the previous one. The problem is that the ifelse function returns a length which is equal to the length of the test. In this case, the length is the one of *shift(x)* and not *x*. Therefore I end up with the first element (or the last, if using type = "lead", instead of the default "lag") of each column turned into NA.

Here a MWE:

```
a <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(4,5,6,7,8,8,9)
data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
f <- function(x) {
ifelse(x==shift(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
}
apply(data, 2, f)
```

Therefore I thought I could change the **ifelse** function: I've done a few attempts to change the **length.out** but I haven't succeeded yet

```
function (test, yes, no) 
{
if (is.atomic(test)) {
    if (typeof(test) != "logical") 
        storage.mode(test) <- "logical"
    if (length(test) == 1 && is.null(attributes(test))) {
        if (is.na(test)) 
            return(NA)
        else if (test) {
            if (length(yes) == 1 && is.null(attributes(yes))) 
              return(yes)
        }
        else if (length(no) == 1 && is.null(attributes(no))) 
            return(no)
    }
}
else test <- if (isS4(test)) 
    methods::as(test, "logical")
else as.logical(test)
ans <- test
ok <- !(nas <- is.na(test))
if (any(test[ok])) 
    ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & 
        ok]
if (any(!test[ok])) 
    ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test & 
        ok]
ans[nas] <- NA
ans
}
```

**EDIT**

My original code was:

```
copy <- copy(data)
for (j in 1: ncol(copy)) {
    for (i in 2: nrow(copy)) {
        if (copy[i,j] == copy[i-1,j] & !is.na(copy[i,j]) & !is.na(copy[i-1,j]))  {
            copy[i,j] <- copy[i-1,j] + (0.0001*sd(copy[,j], na.rm = T))
        }
    }
}
```

but using it with large matrices may cause slow running time. This deals with multiple repetitions. 
The goal was to get to a vectorised, quicker method using a function and apply.

Comment: You should specify that `shift` is in the `data.table` package. Also, have you thought about how you handle the case where you have multiple repetitions? As in `c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3)`?

Comment: Why not simply do: 

`f <- function(x) {
  out <- ifelse(x==shift(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x);
  out[1] <- x[1];
  out
}`

Comment: @antoine-sac thank you it works! I knew it wasn't something diffucult but could you please explain me the reasoning behind it? I'm a beginner

Comment: Aside from `ifelse` you could, also, use `sapply(data, function(x) { i = c(FALSE, x[-1] == x[-length(x)]); x[i] = x[i] + 0.001 * sd(x, na.rm = TRUE); x })`

Comment: @alexis_laz thank you it works! can you explain me a bit the logic? as I said before, I'm a beginner. Moreover, this doesn't deal with multiple repetitions, as antoine-sac was suggesting

Comment: @Giacomo : Basically, you need find indices where 'after == previous', so (1) subsetting and comparing all-but-first (`x[-1]`) and all-but-last (`x[-length(x)]`) and (2) appending a `FALSE` at start to have an output of `length(x)` and ignore the `x[1]`, you get the indices ("logical" vector) where 'after == previous'. Then, all is needed, is replacing those indices of `x` with appropriate values

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I've seen that it works also with simple apply, is there any strong difference in using one or the other? What about multiple repetitions?

Comment: @Giacomo : `apply` coerces to "matrix" before applying any function (so, for example, if a column in your "data.frame" is "character" the "data.frame" is converted to a "character" "matrix" etc.) -- "data.frame" is a "list"-like structure and, so, `(l|s)apply` is more generally preferred. For multiple repetitions see `?rle` to identify consecutive occurences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, your approach leads to a `NA` in the first element of the vector returned by `f`. This first element is not similar to the previous (since there is none), so we would like to have the first value unchanged.

A straightforward approach is to do just that. Apologies, it does not answer your title question although it does solve your problem.

```
f <- function(x) { 
    # storing the output of ifelse in a variable
    out <- ifelse(x==shift(x), x + 0.001* sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)
    # changing the first element of `out` into first element of x 
    out[1] <- x[1]
    # returning `out` -- in a R function, 
    # the last thing evaluated is returned
    out 
}
```

Note that this will not take care properly of elements repeated more than twice (e.g. `c(1,2,2,2,3)`). Also, this will change all your element the same way. So in `c(1,2,2,1,2,2)`, all the second twos will be changed the same way. This may or mat not be something you want.

You could hack something (a comment suggests `?rle`), but I suggest changing the way you randomize your data, if this makes sense with your particular data.

Instead of adding `0.001*sd`, maybe you could add a gaussian noise with this standard dev? This depends on your application obviously.

```
f <- function(x) { 
    # adding gaussian noise with small sd to repeated values
    # storing the output in a variable `out`
    out <- ifelse(x==shift(x), 
                  x + rnorm(length(x), mean=0, 
                            sd=0.01*sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  x)
    # changing the first element of `out` into first element of x 
    out[1] <- x[1]
    # returning `out` -- in a R function, 
    # the last thing evaluated is returned
    out 
}
```

It depends on what is your purpose for getting rid of exact duplicated values.

Comment: I've tried rle, not sure if I like it. I should set sth like if rle(x)>1 then add the noise isn't it? However, you solution does it for my problem

Comment: The idea is that if you add a *random* noise, then you don't need a special treatment for more than two repetitions, because the modified values are different. For example, f(c(1,2,2,2,3)) just gave me `c(1, 2, 1.98312516884853, 2.00768469913142, 3)`.

Comment: No, using `rle` is more complicated than this. You would need to extract the `lengths` component of the list returned by `rle()`.

Comment: yes sorry i meant the lengths, by the way thank you I learned a lot